# Intuition behind augmented filtration

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, filtrations

Consider an probability space $(\Omega, A,P)$ and the augmented filtration $F(t)= \bigcap_{s>t} \sigma(F^W(t) \cup N),$ where $F^W$ is the natural filtration of an Browian motion $W$ and $N$ the nullsets of $A$.

Why do I need to add in these nullsets in order to make $W$ adapted?

What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: Remember that Brownian motion needs to be *modified* in order to ensure continuity : that's what Kolmogorov's continuity theorem says. However, the sets that require modification are null sets, which are *not necessarily* measurable with respect to the Brownian filtration. To allow these modifications to take place, one needs to allow the filtration to be flexible with respect to these measure-zero changes in the process : so the best way to do that is to augment it.

Comment: Even if you start with a continuous version of the BM (which you can get from other constructions) and take the natural filtration of this so that you may feel augmentation is unnecessary, it is still the case that asserting simple things such as hitting times of regular enough sets being stopping times will require completeness of the filtration, and augmentation is the best way to ensure that these deficiencies are taken care of, and one can work freely in this setup.

Comment: (Lastly, I'd like to know your source, and where you are reading from. I'd imagine this is from a book involving Brownian motion, but if you gave me some details I'll be able to help you look further from the context of the book you are reading, as to why augmentation is necessary.)